# MATLAB find function translate to python - 3 input arguments version

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, code-translation

In MATALAB I can write easily:

```
ind = find(X, k, 'last')
```

that returns at most the last k indices corresponding to the nonzero entries of X.

Numpy has the [`numpy.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) function just for the MATALAB `find(X)`, the one parameter version.

Which is numpythonic way to translate `find` with 3 arguments?

Comment: Check out the [Mathesaurus](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html) page. (The webpage is awesome and helped me go from `Matlab` to `R`).

Comment: The `numpy` find returns a `tuple` - one array for each dimension.  Do the normal indexing on this tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent expression is

```
# importing numpy as np and
# assign a ndarray to x
ind = np.nonzero(x)[-k:]
```

Using slicing you replace the use of *'last'* argument.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to apply the last or first k through array slicing of the result.